# Helidon: GraphQL with Stream and Defer annotation

Tags: graphql, stream, java-stream, graphql-java, helidon

I am working on a graphql API using Helidon MP and looking to confirm that directives @ stream and @defer supportable?
GraphQL documentation link for reference: https://graphql.org/blog/2020-12-08-improving-latency-with-defer-and-stream-directives/

we tried GraphQL @stream and @defer annotation but its not working. We could make it work in Apollo server.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert in our (Helidon's) GraphQL support. I do know that we support the MicroProfile GraphQL 2.0 spec. https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-graphql-2.0/microprofile-graphql-spec-2.0.html After a quick read of that I do not see any mention of `@defer` or `@stream` nor do I find references in our codebase to those. So I do not think our Helidon implementation supports these.

I will point a colleague who is closer to our GraphQL support than I am to this question in hopes he can be more helpful. Wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: I heard back from our expert and, as I suspected, Helidon's GraphQL support does not include `@defer` or `@stream`. Feel free to add an enhancement request here https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/new/choose and we can evaluate it for inclusion. Thanks.